# Confusion over 'extern' keyword in C

Tags: c, extern

I get that in C, variable definitions and declarations are done similarly except when we use the keyword extern, for eg in the following code:

```
extern int i;

int main () {

..

int i = 1;

..

}
```

I know that 'i' is declared outside 'main' but memory for it is allocated inside 'main'. I have two questions:
(i) Is i a stack variable or a variable on the data segment (global variable)?
(ii) What is i's scope? Can it be seen outside the above .c file if executables of both files are linked together at runtime, or do we need the extern int i; declaration in each file?

Please help? I am not familiar with languages other than C/C++; hence I am having a hard time understanding the difference between variable definition and variable declaration.

Comment: It's a long time since I wrote any C, but as far as I recall, the answer is that you have two variables called 'i' - one defined locally to the main function, and another which is supposed to be defined in some other file.

Comment: *I know that 'i' is declared outside 'main' but memory for it is allocated inside 'main'*. No, not exactly. There are *two* different `i` variables declared. One is is an external global variable `i` (assumed to be declared elsewhere) and the other is local to the `main` function. So, yes, there is memory on the stack allocated for the local `i`, but it's different than the global memory allocated for the external `i`. The when you refer to `i` inside of `main`, it sees the local one, not the global one.

Comment: The same identifier can denote different entities at different points in the program. The variable `i` declared outside of `main` function has _file scope_ and _external linkage_ . The variable `i` defined inside of `main` function has _block scope_ and _no linkage_ . Those are two distinct entities.

Comment: 'I know that 'i' is declared outside 'main' but memory for it is allocated inside 'main': false. You have two variables. (i) There are two `i`s so the answer is 'both'. (ii) The `extern i`'s scope is global; the method-local `i`'s scope is method-local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern int i;` declares, but does not define `i`. If this `i` is used and there is no definition of it somewhere, linking would generally fail. If it did not have the `extern`, so it just said `int i;` or `int i = 0;`, it would define `i`. (The former is a tentative definition, which acts a default if there is no non-tentative definition.)

Since the `int i;` is inside a block (a sequence of statements enclosed by `{` and `}`, in this case the block that defines `main`), it defines a new object. The name `i` refers to different things outside `main` and inside this block (but after the definition `int i;`).

The scope of the `i` declared by `extern int i;` is the entire file from its declaration to the end. (That scope includes the block in `main`, but this `i` is hidden by the `int i;` inside the block. Technically, the scope of the first `i` includes that region—it is present but hidden and inaccessible.) Declaring names with `extern` does not extend their scope beyond the current file. Rather, it gives them *linkage*, which means they can made to refer to the same object declared with the same name in another file.

The scope of the `i` declared by `int i;` is from its declaration to the end of the block it is declared in.

The `i` defined inside `main` is generally allocated on the stack by common compilers, if it is actually needed. (If the program does not actually use it, or the compiler can eliminate uses of it by optimization or fold them into other expressions, it may not need to actually allocate any stack space for it.) The object referred to by this `i` has no relationship to any object referred to by `i` outside of the block.